# select data from multi-column index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hi I have a dataFrame which looks like below:
[image: **strong text**]

I want just select data on males, so I used

```
data_Male = data.loc[:, data.columns.get_level_values(0) == 'Male']
```

However dataFrame data_Male is empty, why is that? how to select then?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Pandas documentation ([get_level_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html#pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values) and [advanced indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)), this should be a valid selection.

I can successfully recreate it with this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'], ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=index)
df_subselect = df.loc[:,df.columns.get_level_values(0)=='bar']

print (df_subselect)
```

Alternatively, you could access the subset of your dataframe using (but this will not retain the original multi-level index):

```
df['bar']
df.loc[:,'bar']
```

Could your issue be with the input data?

Answer (score 0):

Is the DataFrame recognizing "Male" as a column?

You could first try `df.columns` to see it. If it is, you could use `df["Male"]` to obtain the result and assign it to a new DataFrame.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.query()` for selecting from multiple indexed dataframe. If you have more than one criterium, you can combine them with `&` within your query:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2,2, 4], 'B': [10, 20, 50, 80], 'C': [6, 7, 8, 9]})
df.set_index(['A', 'B'])

df

[Output]
      C
A B
1 10  6
2 20  7
  50  8
4 80  9

df.query("A == 2")

[Output]
      C
A B
2 20  7
  50  8

df.query("B == 10")

[Output]
      C
A B
1 10  6

df.query("A == 2 & B == 20")

[Output]
      C
A B
2 20  7
```